# expect statement works for $scope, how do I get my init() function in Karma test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine

I have a Karma test spec like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: RegistrationCtrl', function () {

  beforeEach(module('stageApp'));

  var RegistrationCtrl, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    RegistrationCtrl = $controller('RegistrationCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

      it('should exist', function () {
      expect(RegistrationCtrl.init).toBeDefined();
  });


  it('should exist', function () {
      expect(scope.testPassword).toBeDefined();
  });


});
```

I'm trying to access the init function in my controller that was declared like this:

```
var init = function () {

          $scope.showProfileFeatures = false;
};
```

My test for scope.testPassword works just fine, the test for init() fails. In addition to trying it with RegistrationCtrl.init, I've also tried just 'init' and that fails as well.

here is the working test password function in my controller:

```
$scope.testPassword = function ($event) {

          var password = $scope.regPassword;   
          if (password.length < 8) {
              alert("bad password");
          }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`init` is not a public function on your controller. You need to do `$scope.init` whereas you have `var init = ...`

Comment: I figured that I would have to do something like that, I will try that out and let you know if it worked. I've been learning unit testing with Karma and still getting used to syntax etc.

Comment: This is one of those situations where this fixes one thing and breaks another. The page code requires that init function not to be decorated with $scope otherwise it breaks code elsewhere in the page.